# syntax analzer for python language

Tags: python

I am creating a syntax analyzer for ***PYTHON
*** language.  Does anyone know the lexical rules and grammar for **STRINGS** in python?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

I take it you mean for string literals?  The syntax is defined [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).  But really, you shouldn't bother re-inventing the wheel when the python [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module already does what you want (provides a lexical analyzer for python).